# How to show audio html src from URL.createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I got the content with content-type audio/wav. and I think I already get the content to become a blob and file and make the url for it so I can show the audio in  tag in html. this is my javascript code how I do that

```
    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
      var blob = new Blob([response], {
        'type': 'audio/wav'
      });
      console.log(blob);
      const file = new File([blob], "hasil.wav", {
        type: blob.type,
        lastModified: Date.now()
      });
      console.log(file);

      var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      console.log(url);
      var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

      var source = document.getElementById('audioSource');
      source.src = url;

      audio.load();
    });
  })
```

and this is my html

```
<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
    <source id="audioSource" src="">
     </source>
     Your browser does not support the audio format.
</audio>
```

and from that I got this in my console

[image]

but the audio tag in html still cannot play the audio. is there anyone know what is wrong with this? please help

Comment: Make sure the data is treated as binary(which is not the default)

Comment: do you know how to do that?

Comment: Post how you set your `settings` variable